# How to add link or code in comment area

Tags: discussion, support, comments

If I am adding some comments to user post, how do I add like this `Code` (preview in view, should appear within gray background) or if I add some link on their post [link](http://fb.com) (preview as Hyperlink).

Comment: `The same way` [you just did](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291214/1380752) or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: User back ticks `\`content\`` for code, and the `[link text](url)` for links [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291214/how-to-add-link-or-code-in-comment-area)

Comment: See also [comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: There's a little [help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) link under the `Add Comment` button if you ever need to be reminded

Comment: @CharleneVas this was almost 4 year and there is an accepted the answer. try something new

Comment: test ` tes ` [test]

Comment: By default questions/answers add hyperlinks as `[text][1]` and at end of question/answer `[1]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291214/5569922`. This is called a [reference-style link](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links) in Markdown. It is quite useful to also know the format ryanyuyu points out `[text](url)`, which is called inline-style links.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Comments can use a [scaled back](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) version of Markdown.

- To use code formatting in a comment, utilize the backticks (`` ` ``) around the code you want to format

Example:

`` This is a block of `code` `` formats to "This is a block of `code`"

- To use links, you do this utilize the format `[display text](url)`

Example:

`[This is a link to comment help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)` displays as "[This is a link to comment help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)"

Comment: what if the text includes paranthesis?

Comment: @D.Jones Then it looks like this: [This is a link to comment help]

Comment: @D.Jones it can be included without any escaping e.g. [This is a link (StackOverflow) to comment help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: [It isn't working?](www.google.com)

Comment: [try another one](http://www.example.com)

Comment: long links won't fit but you can't use link shorteners? that one doesn't add

Answer (score 11):

I recently made a link out of a chunk of code that will show up as:

[`$(array1).filter(array2);`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

By typing the following:

```
<a href="http://api.jquery.com/filter/">`$(array1).filter(array2);`</a>
```

Comment: [test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0)

Comment: [https://imgur.com/a/Am2Z8zH](https://imgur.com/a/Am2Z8zH) another test

Comment: [test](google.com)  long links don't work what a barf

Comment: (more parens [test](google.com)

Comment: no parens [test](google.com)

Comment: (more parens [test](http://www.google.com))

Comment: [test](https://google.com)